# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de actualizar mi `dataTable` cada cierto tiempo desde el `Controller` con el siguiente código.

```
if (tiempMilisegundos > 0) {
            timer = new Timer(tiempMilisegundos, new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    obtenerCatalogos();
                    org.primefaces.context.RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(
                            "tablaAlertasCped");
                }
            });

            timer.start();
        }
```

Pero al momento de llegar al RequestContex muestra el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.primefaces.context.RequestContext.getCurrentInstance(RequestContext.java:39)
>     at
>   mx.gob.sat.matce.rni.web.controller.AlertasController.obtenerCatalogos(AlertasController.java:235)
>     at
>   mx.gob.sat.matce.rni.web.controller.AlertasController$1.actionPerformed(AlertasController.java:198)
>     at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:291)    at
>   javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:221)     at
>   java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)     at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:642)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:603)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:601)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:612)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)

Alguien sabrá el motivo, he probado el `request` fuera del `timer` y si funciona pero dentro de el ya no.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Answer (score 2):

`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance()` te está devolviendo `null`, y aunque no te ayude en tu problema, este compartamiento es normal.

El `RequestContext` de PrimeFaces requiere que pueda acceder al JSF `FacesContext`. Pero este último solo es accesible desde un thread que esté procesando un *request* (pedido) JSF.

Cuando usas un `Timer`, este ejecuta tu código en un thread distinto que no sabe nada de JSF, ni del `FacesContext`, por eso te devuelve `null`.

Referencias en inglés:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15707638/4955425
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14394992/4955425