# SU COLABORACION CON ESTE CODIGO

Tags: java, netbeans

tengo este error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
Al momento de guardar los datos en un formulario
este es el código, AL MOMENTO DE CORRERLO y darle click en guardar me sale ese error, no se que mas podria hacer por favor su ayuda, muchas gracias, adjunto el codigo

```
public class form_huesped {
    
    private static form_huesped formulario;
    private static Persona persona[];
    private static int cont;
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    formulario = new form_huesped();
    persona = new Persona[100]; // creamos el arreglo para agregar los elementos 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        persona[i] = new Persona();
     }
    
    cont = 0;
    
}
// se crean los metodos para guardar o buscar 

    public static void guardar(int c, String n, String co , int tel ){
        
        //creamos cuatro variables
        //Cedula n, Nombre n, Correo co, Telefono tel 
        persona[cont].setCedula(c);
        persona[cont].setNombre(n);
        persona[cont].setCorreo(co);
        persona[cont].setTelefono(tel);
                    
        cont++;
    
}
    public static void buscar (String bus){
        //Creamos la variable 
        //Buscar bus 
        for (int j  = 0; j  < persona.length; j ++) {
            
            if(persona[j].getNombre().equals(bus)){
            //    formulario.cargar_datos(persona[j]);
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115801/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-nullpointerexception)